# JSF outputLink rendered underlined

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Good evening. I followed the tutorials of [primefaces](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/tooltip.jsf) to use some of its controls, I used the outputLink:

```
<h:outputText value="Fade: " />  
<h:outputLink id="fade" value="#">  
    <h:outputText value="Fade Effect" />  
</h:outputLink>
```

the outputLink got underlined on mouseover however when I tried to use it, it's rendered in the page underlined by default, I want to know why that happens?

Comment: It's a JSF component. And where is `<p:tooltip for="fade" value="Fade effect is used by default" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" />` from the showcase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom CSS is being used on the showcase website. Investigating the CSS used on the link show this:

[image]

The rule: `text-decoration: none;` comes from `default.css` which does not belong to a Primefaces Theme.

I tested using `<p:tooltip for="fade" value="Fade effect is used by default" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" />`, but the underline is still there on my version (3.3). So that is not the reason.